# ¿Porqué no puedo castear una columna character varying a integer en todos los registros de una tabla con un select?

Tags: postgresql

Estoy intentando castear una columna, donde sus valores son character varying y quiero converirlos a int, cuando pongo un limit 1 si se castea pero cuando hago el select de todos los registros muestra el siguiente error:

```
La sintaxis de entrada no es válida para integer: <<>> SQL state 22P02
```

La consulta es la siguiente:

```
select dni::integer from registro.profesor
```

Comment: Tienes datos en esa columna que no son números, como debes de saber, un espacio espacio en blanco no es un número o un guión

Comment: Gracias..amigo @YoAlbert lo probé y tal cual mencionas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Significa que alguna de las entradas no es casteable a integer: Si algún DNI tiene letra, o tiene un espacio donde no debe (o empieza quizá por 0) no se podrá hacer la conversión

Comment: Gracias si era eso :D